# Error "Requirement already satisfied" when `pip install openpyxl`

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have win10 (64-bits) and I'm using python 3.6.2

I've tried : `$ pip install openpyxl` on the cmd but got the following error:

```
> C:\Users\Joctã Argôlo>pip install openpyxl
> Collecting openpyxl Using
> cached openpyxl-2.4.8.tar.gz Requirement already satisfied: jdcal in
> c:\users\joctãargôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) 
> Requirement already satisfied: et_xmlfile in c:\users\joctãargôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) 
> Installing collected packages: openpyxl   Running setup.py
> install for openpyxl ... error Exception:
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "c:\users\joctãargôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
>    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)  
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 56: invalid continuation byte
> ```
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "c:\users\joctãargôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
>   status = self.run(options, args)   
> File "c:\users\joctã argôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
>   prefix=options.prefix_path,   
> File "c:\users\joctã argôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
>   **kwargs   
> File "c:\users\joctã argôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
>   spinner=spinner,   
> File "c:\users\joctã argôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
>   line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())   
> File "c:\users\joctãargôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
>   return s.decode('utf_8') 
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 56: invalid continuation byte
> ```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you updated `pip` recently? Looks like this was a bug fixed in this thread: [Another attempt to fix encoding issues #4486](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4486): try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, or `pip install https://github.com/pypa/pip` should also work.

Comment: pip is already up-to-date

Comment: ok, that's good. maybe try this https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4110#issuecomment-302927949 which describes modifying `/site-packages/pip/compat/__init__.py`

Comment: Also, maybe it is fixed only in `pip` versions 10 and above, as mentioned in this comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4110#issuecomment-304476523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error always happen when you have your folder named in some crazy letters.
"**Joctã Argôlo**"

In this way error say to us "Hey man! What the hell you put in me??!!"

1. Or rename your user folder, if you know how
2. Or change file

> c:\users\joctã
>   argôlo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py

```
return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
```

to

```
return s.decode('cp1251')
```

**cp1251** - is my solution from russians language ([From my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269756/pip-install-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe0-in-positi/48272136#48272136)). Put your own encoding(Portugale?) in which you have a folder. You must know her.
And as long as you do not change the name of the user's folder - do not change the entry in the python file back. **Updates will not solve the problem**.