# pip install & UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 9: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pip

Try install:

```
pip install python-binance
```

Result:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 9: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 9: invalid continuation byte
```

How to solve?

Comment: It seems like a known [issue](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues)

Comment: Not helped. I was installed Microsoft Visual Tools 2015.

Comment: I believe this is only an issue because your path uses unicode characters that is not being parsed correctly through CMD code page. Installing from Visual Studio bypasses CMD. There may be `chcp` tricks you can play (`chcp 65001` to force utf8) but ymmv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OKAY...

1. Since the error was in my file:

   > c:\users\анна\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat__init__.py

The problem folder was '**анна**' which was is **cp1251**

2. The first solution is to find how to rename the user's folder. (except for reinstalling the operating system). To the folder with the Latin alphabet
3. The second path in the file **compat__init__.py** - replace

   `return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)`
4. into

   `return s.decode('cp1251')`

Of course you need to know what encoding you have. At me it **cp1251**, at you it can be **latin** (for an example). After the replacement in the file - everything was installed successfully!

Thanks 2  cowbert

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using quick fix for such situations. The fix is done by redirecting the output from standard direction (terminal) to file like this:

```
pip install python-binance > temp_output_file
```

and open it if you need...

Comment: It lets you install the package. Since the issue rise when pip install procces tries to output to terminal in different codepage. This trick just redirect the output and avoid this to happen

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use PowerShell (or VS Code terminal) instead of CMD. It worked alright.

The problem originates in Windows' old terminal CMD, which in eastern europe defaultly uses cp855, that can cause en/de-coding problems.