# Error when trying to install coloredlogs

Tags: python

Ok so I'm trying to install coloredlogs with pip using the following command

```
requests==2.14.2ruamel.yaml==0.15.35coloredlogs==9.0terminaltables==3.1.0
```

It successfully install everything except coloredlogs. I'm running python 3.6 by the way.

When trying to install coloredlogs, here's what I'm getting:

```
Collecting coloredlogs
  Using cached coloredlogs-9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting humanfriendly>=4.7 (from coloredlogs)
  Using cached humanfriendly-4.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from coloredlogs)
Collecting pyreadline; sys_platform == "win32" (from humanfriendly>=4.7->coloredlogs)
  Using cached pyreadline-2.1.zip
Installing collected packages: pyreadline, humanfriendly, coloredlogs
  Running setup.py install for pyreadline ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 91: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 91: invalid continuation byte
```

I also tried installing doing

```
pip install coloredlogs
```

and

```
python -m pip install coloredlogs
```

but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Maybe updating pip will help? `pip install --upgrade pip `. Just guessing :D

Comment: Also try that: [https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4998#issuecomment-361014560](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4998#issuecomment-361014560) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269756/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269756/pip-install-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe0-in-positi)

Comment: yes worked thank you

Comment: Could you tell me which of these helped, so I can add this as an answer?

Comment: the first link worked for me

Comment: You can accept the answer now. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows cmd execute: `chcp 65001` and CodePage changes to UTF-8.

Source: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4998#issuecomment-361014560